# SignalR with Angular 10 and ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, angular, signalr, signalr-hub

I am trying to implement SignalR in an ASP.NET (not Core) and Angular (currently 10) application.
Startup.cs is using Owin.

Every documentation or example I could find was for either ASP.NET Core or wasn't using Angular so could someone point me in a good direction?

The closest I could find for this combo was this guide: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-signalr-angular2-and-typescript-real-time-clock/, however I keep getting "Cannot read property 'hubConnection' of undefined" error, probably because I don't understand what '$' is doing in the SignalRService class since I started working with Angular 7 and above.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: <script src="../Scripts/jquery.signalR.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  there does the $ come from

Comment: You are more likely to get a useful answer if you narrow this down to a specific question, possibly with a minimal code example. Asking generally, how do I. get SignalR to work with Angular 7 is just too broad and doesn't fit this format.

Answer (score 10):

U can use the example in this link [SignalR using Angular 10](https://dev.to/jaguacdaco/how-to-build-a-performant-signalr-chat-spa-using-angular-10-and-net-core-3-1-4ghn)

Steps:

1. Install the needed signalr library

> npm i @microsoft/signalr@latest --save

2. Import the needed classes

> import { HubConnection, HubConnectionBuilder, LogLevel } from
> '@microsoft/signalr';

3. Connect to hub

> ```
> this._hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
>   .withUrl('http://localhost:52864/chathub')
>   .build();
> ```

4. Listen to methods on the hub

> ```
> this._hubConnection.on('MessageReceived', (message) => {
>   console.log(message);
> });
> ```

5. Start the connection

> ```
> this._hubConnection.start()
>   .then(() => console.log('connection started'))
>   .catch((err) => console.log('error while establishing signalr connection: ' + err));
> ```

How the dummy example looks like:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HubConnection, HubConnectionBuilder, LogLevel } from '@microsoft/signalr';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-messaging',
  templateUrl: './messaging.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./messaging.component.scss']
})
export class MessagingComponent implements OnInit {
  private _hubConnection: HubConnection;

  constructor(private _httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.connect();
  }

  public onSendButtonClick(): void {
    this._hubConnection.send('SendMessage', 'test message').then(r => { });
  }

  private connect(): void {
    this._hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl('http://localhost:52864/chathub')
      .build();

    this._hubConnection.on('MessageReceived', (message) => {
      console.log(message);
    });

    this._hubConnection.start()
      .then(() => console.log('connection started'))
      .catch((err) => console.log('error while establishing signalr connection: ' + err));
  }
}
```

Note: no need to install the 'signalr-protocol-msgpack'

Comment: I don't know why this has more upvotes
This doesn't work with ASP NET 4.5 OWIN

Answer (score 3):

The old (not core) SignalR javascript client depends on jQuery.
So the best way to add support for SignalR in your angular app is first

1. Add jquery and signalr npm packages to your project

   npm install jquery signalr --save
2. Add @types/jquery and @types/signalr npm packages for typing support for both packages.

   npm install @types/jquery @types/signalr --save-dev
3. Edit your angular.json file projects/[projectname]/architect/build/scripts node to include both jquery and signalr scripts (See example for full file below)

   "scripts": [
   "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
   "./node_modules/signalr/jquery.signalR.js"
   ]
4. Edit tsconfig.app.json file and add "jquery","signalr" to the "compilerOptions"/"types" list. (see example for full file below)

Here is how angular.json should look like (project name here is signalr demo)

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "signalrdemo": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/signalrdemo",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "./node_modules/signalr/jquery.signalR.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "signalrdemo:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "signalrdemo:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "signalrdemo:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "signalrdemo:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "signalrdemo:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }},
  "defaultProject": "signalrdemo"
}
```

Here is how tsconfig.app.json should look like:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
    "types": ["jquery","signalr"]
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hello @SherifElmetainy, thank you for answering. Unfortuantely, this did not resolve my issue completely. I'm still getting "Cannot read property 'hubConnection' of undefined" error in SignalRService class. Do you perhaps know how to tell that class the script exists? Tried adding the script to html file of the component I'm trying to use SignalR in, html of the parent where module.ts is and in the index.html file.

Comment: No adding script to the HTML won't help. It needs to be added to angular.json. 

Cannot read property hubConnection of undefined means that the $ symbol is undefined, and this is defined by jquery. So the jquery script must be included, and the way to included it an an angular application is by adding it to angular.json scripts.

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something obvious, I'm new to SignalR and jQuery in general.

I've added the scripts to angular.json.

If I use 'import * as $ from "jquery";' I get 'ERROR TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.hubConnection is not a function' 

and if I use 'var $: any;' I get the before mentioned unidentified error.

Comment: I have the same issue. I am not sure if its something to do with Angular and strict mode, but unable to get through the error : `Property 'connection' does not exist on type 'JQueryStatic'`

Answer (score 1):

I made the simple mistake of not declaring the jQuery symbol above the declaration of the Service:

```
declare var $: any;
```

e.g.

```
declare var $: any;  
@Injectable()  
export class SignalRService {  ...
```

This link on how to use jQuery with Angular clued me in:

https://blog.bitsrc.io/how-to-use-jquery-with-angular-when-you-absolutely-have-to-42c8b6a37ff9

Answer (score 0):

Signalr depends on jquery so first, you need to install

```
npm install signalr
npm install jquery
```

and their types

```
npm install --save @types/jquery
npm install --save @types/signalr
```

Add scripts to angular-cli.json

```
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      ...
      "options": {
        "scripts": [
          "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
          "node_modules/signalr/jquery.signalR.min.js"
        ]
    ...
```

Create signalr.service.ts file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

declare var $: any;

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SignalrService {

  private connection: any;
  private proxy: any;

  constructor() { }

  public initializeSignalRConnection(): void {
    this.connection = $.hubConnection(`${your_server_baseUrl}/signalr_map`, { useDefaultPath: false });
// Please note that by default '/signalr' URL will be used to connect to your SignalR service. Providing 'useDefaultPath' allows you to customize it
    this.proxy = this.connection.createHubProxy('connectionHub');

    this.proxy.on('messageReceived', (serverMessage) => this.onMessageReceived(serverMessage));

    this.connection.start().done((data: any) => {
      console.log('Connected to Connection Hub');
      this.sendMessage();
    }).catch((error: any) => {
      console.log('Connection Hub error:' + error);
    });
  }

  public sendMessage(): void {
    this.proxy.invoke('ClientMessage', 'My message')
      .catch((error: any) => {
        console.log('sending message error -> ' + error);
      });
  }

  private onMessageReceived(serverMessage: string) {
    console.log('New message received from Server: ' + serverMessage);
  }

}
```

don't forget to declare jquery symbol

```
declare var $: any;
```

and now you can use your signalr service in the component:

```
constructor(private signalRService: SignalrService) { 
  this.signalRService.initializeSignalRConnection()
}
```

hope this helps